# How to embed database to in an application?

Tags: java, c#

I download a small desktop application.This application stores many information.How they embed database into an application without database setup in computer.I made several search but i don't really understand.

-Are they store this kind of information in txt files?
Thanks in Advance ...

Comment: https://www.google.es/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=embedded+database&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=zELKVOmXKMbOaLTEgMAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases usually thinks in records.  If you compare a database table with an Excel spreadsheet that would be a complete row.  When you define the database table, you need to tell the database how much space each record will need so it is easy to calculate where any given row number is located simply by multiplying the row number with the space needed for each row.

In the Windows and Linux world most databases are designed to be stand-alone and the various programs needing their services connect with TCP/IP.

Some can also run embedded, where they are part of your application and only service that application which then can fully configure the database.  For Java, a typical example is Apache Derby.

Comment: The application which I download file size is 5MB however Derby has 19MB. Why is it so small?

Comment: The Derby download contains more than you need to distribute with your own application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sqlite, that is very aprropriate for your purpose.
See http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to save the data. An Application can use simple text files, proprietary binary files or even a full embedded database like SQLite.

For C# there is an easy way like using the application properties, which are automatically saved to disk by the Framework.